# Validación de un Input en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Disculpen estoy intentado hacer una validación con javaScript de un input que solo acepte 9 números enteros y 4 decimales. He estado investigando pero sólo encuentro la forma de que acepte cierto número de decimales.

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

```
Elementos <input type="number">
```

no soportan el uso del atributo pattern para hacer que los valores ingresados se ajusten a un patrón de expresión regular específico.

> Si quieres ingresar un valor que requiere decimales, necesitarás
> reflejar esto en el valor step así te permite 4 decimales. Por
> defecto, el incremento es 1,  puedes usar el atributo step para
> permitir entradas decimales

[input number step](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

```
<input type="number" placeholder="1.4575" step="0.0001" min="0" max="9">
```